# Bad error wording&link when voting in the primary election phase not having sufficient rep

Tags: bug, reputation, voting, election

When I try to vote for / against a candidate in the primary election phase, e.g. [the election on Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/election/1?tab=primary) and don't have the sufficient rep (which is 150 in case of Code Review), the popup misleadingly tells you that "Vote up / down requires 150 rep" and links to the /help/privileges/vote-up and /help/privileges/vote-down respectively.

> [image]

Which is actually wrong and the linked pages obviously tell that voting up / down requires 15 / 125 rep accordingly.

The sidebar tells however, that to vote for a candidate, you need 150 rep:

> Any community member with 150 reputation may vote in the primary.

Though, as the wording of the error popup is still misleading, I'd propose to change it to something like:

> Voting for / against the candidates requires 150 reputation

(probably it can be shortened a bit, as looks quite long)

Comment: @hich Oh, sorry... was going to tag it as bug, that's strange.